# Solving 1 equation with 4 variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, prime-factorization

In my research, I came up with this equation which consists of 4 variables (t,m,g,h).

$$4tm(t-m)(t+m)=h(\sqrt{3}g-h)(\sqrt{3}g+h)$$

Initially, I attempted in equating each product on LHS and RHS, as follows

(i)  $4tm=h$, $t-m=\sqrt{3}g-h$, $t+m=\sqrt{3}g+h$

(ii) $4tm=h$, $t-m=\sqrt{3}g+h$, $t+m=\sqrt{3}g-h$

...

(vi) $4tm=\sqrt{3}g+h$, $t-m=\sqrt{3}g-h$, $t+m=h$

Under all these assumptions, I manage to proof contradictions that no such solutions exist.

Later on I was thinking that these assumptions might not be correct, because `8*6*4=2*3*32`, in which no factors on both sides of the equality are equal. These are only correct iff both sides of the equality are product of different primes. Hence, to apply (i) to (vi), I should first of all establish that the factors on both sides of this equality are primes (no idea yet on how to do that, perhaps work with the prime power decomposition). Can someone help me shed some light on how to tackle this problem. I need to figure out if there exist solutions or not to this equation.

Comment: Given that there is a square root in the equation, I assume the variables are real numbers, rather than integers? In that case it makes no sense to match up factors. For any values of $t$ and $m$ you can put $g=0$ and $h=-(4tm(t-m)(t+m))^{1/3}$ to make the equation true. And even for any other value of $g$ the equation is just a cubic in $h$ which will have at least one real root.

Comment: With just positive integers, there are solutions, too. For example you can get $12144$ with $(t,m)=(12,11)$ and $(g,h)=(16,3)$.

Comment: Sorry in my question i forgot to mention that all 4 variables are non zero and distinct. All solutions that i am looking for are integers..

Comment: Wow thanks for pointing out the existence of solutions..clearly my assumptions are incorrect..